# Symfony: passing object to controller method

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm following this guide in order to create a RESTFUL api:
http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

In POST section, it uses object User as input of its edit method. I'm trying to do the same with my controller class, but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request
>   information

Can somebody help me?
Thank you

**Update:**

Now the definition of the method looks like this:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/rest/categories/{id}")
   * @ParamConverter("category", class="TouristAppCoreBundle:Category")
   * @Template()
   */
  public function rest_editAction(Category $category)
```

Comment: This error is related to the ParamConverter not being able to guess which field to use when fetching the entity from the database. Did you read the ParamConverter documentation? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Answer (score 0):

hi try this out may be this might help

```
/*
** @ParamConverter("category",options={"id" = "category_id"})
*/
```